# Java class casting throws exception

Tags: java, android, class, casting

I have a super class A, and classes B, C and D that extend A.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}
```

Then I have a list like this:

```
[B.class, C.class, D.class]
```

I take a random item from the list and instantiate it like so:

```
Object obj = list.get(i).newInstance()
```

Now I need to pass obj to a method that accepts objects of type A as a parameter.

```
A a = (A) obj
```

causes java to throw an exception (Either InstantiationException or IllegalAccessException, I don't know because android studio won't stop at breakpoints inside the catch, and any attempt to save information about the exception from the catch results in null...).

I understand why I can't dynamically specify the new object type and then cast obj to that type, but if they all share the common parent, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Can anybody enlighten me how to fix what I'm currently doing, or achieve the same thing in a similar way?

Thanks! /Max

Comment: Can you show your method, how you are invoking it, and the full stacktrace?

Comment: 'Either InstantiationException or IllegalAccessException, I don't know', how do you expect us to know?

Comment: Can you please show the code for newInstance() method as well ?

Comment: @Ankit that's the method from the Java `Class` object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

Comment: Are classes top-level class? Else, if the are inner classes, should be defined static

Comment: @jbs: I was thinking it was more of a general misunderstanding of mine that was causing this issue. I could not get exception information because android-studio was skipping breakpoints on code inside catch blocks that were not a return statement... I will look into this more tonight and try to provide more information

Comment: @answer-providers, perhaps I over simplified my question. Ill provide more code this evening :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end this was due to a bug with android studio. Rewriting the code fixed the problem and I wasn't able to reproduce this issue

Other symptoms that future searchers might find useful:

- android studio would not stop at breakpoints inside a catch block
- Any attempt to save information about the exception inside the catch resulted in null (see example below)

:

```
Exception ex = null;
try {
    // do something that raises an exception
    ex = new Exception();
} catch (Exception ex)  {
    ex = ex;
}
// ex == null
```

As pointed out by the other answers, what I was describing in my question does not normally raise an exception.

Answer (score 6):

The newInstance method can throw an InstantiationException or IllegalAccessException, hence the warning you're probably seeing in your IDE if this call isn't wrapped in a try/catch. Your simple example seems to work fine though.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Class> list = new LinkedList<Class>();
        list.add(B.class);
        list.add(C.class);

        Object obj = list.get(0).newInstance();

        A a = (A) obj;

        System.out.println(a instanceof B);

    }
}
```

Prints "true"

Comment: Thanks, in fact it was an issue with android studio that was causing my issue. I had assumed it was a misunderstanding of mine that meant I was trying to do something unsupported. I tried your sample code and it of course worked fine. Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be working absolutely fine. I am not understanding your question.

```
    package testplayground;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

   class A {

    void print() {
        System.out.println("inside A");
    }
    }

   class B extends A {

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("inside B");
        }
    }

    class C extends A {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("inside C");
    }
    }

    class D extends A {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("inside D");
    }
}

public class TestPlayGround {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>();
            list.add(B.class);
            list.add(C.class);
            list.add(D.class);
            for (Class classObj : list) {
                Object obj = classObj.newInstance();
                A a = (A) obj;
                methodA(a);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void methodA(A a) {
        a.print();
    }
}
```

output:-

inside B

inside C

inside D